# 2013 C# connection to PowerPivot DataModel

Tags: c#, excel, ado, powerpivot, datamodel

This article [Connecting to PowerPivot with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242557/connecting-to-powerpivot-with-c-sharp) is the closest to my question but it seems that it is out of date. I attempted the methods they showed in the answer but the example

```
 ThisWorkbook.Connections["PowerPivot Data"].OLEDBConnection.ADOConnection
```

Does not return the connection information, rather an exception.

But I was able to access the PP Data Model using:

```
ThisAddIn.Current.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Connections[1]. ModelTables[1].ModelTableColumns[1].Name`
```

But the object only allows you to look at the column names in the model. I wasn't able to get the connection information or anything.

```
ThisAddIn.Current.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Connections[1].ModelConnection.ADOConnection`
```

causes an exception and so does:

```
ThisAddIn.Current.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Connections[1].OLEDBConnection.ADOConnection
```

MY QUESTIONS

- Have I made a mistake in my code?
- Is there another method to connect to the datamodel that I haven't listed above?
- Is it possible to read the records in the datamodel? (I was able to read column names)

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Also was able to connect to get name with this

ThisAddIn.Current.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Model.Name;

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> string ConnString = **"Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=$Embedded$;
>   Locale Identifier=1033;Location=" + ThisAddIn.Current.Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName + ";SQLQueryMode=DataKeys"**;
>
> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server OlapServer = new Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server();
>
> OlapServer.Connect(ConnString);